# Java: SAX Parsing a huge XML file

Tags: java, xml, sax

I have a 35 GB XML file (yes, some organizations do that and I have no control over it) that I would like to SAX parse. I found an example here:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/SAXDemo.htm

of how to run a SAX parser and avoid loading everything. However, I get an out of memory error immediatly. Why does this happens and how I can make this code perfectly scalable for any XML file size?

Here my code:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.xml.sax.AttributeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class XMLSAXTools extends org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler {

/**
 * Logging facility
 */
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(XMLSAXTools.class);

private String fileName = "C:/Data/hugefile.xml";
private int counter = 0;

/** The main method sets things up for parsing */
public void test() throws IOException, SAXException,
        ParserConfigurationException {
    // Create a JAXP "parser factory" for creating SAX parsers
    javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

    // Configure the parser factory for the type of parsers we require
    spf.setValidating(false); // No validation required

    // Now use the parser factory to create a SAXParser object
    // Note that SAXParser is a JAXP class, not a SAX class
    javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

    // Create a SAX input source for the file argument
    org.xml.sax.InputSource input = new InputSource(new FileReader(fileName));

    // Give the InputSource an absolute URL for the file, so that
    // it can resolve relative URLs in a <!DOCTYPE> declaration, e.g.
    input.setSystemId("file://" + new File(fileName).getAbsolutePath());

    // Create an instance of this class; it defines all the handler methods
    XMLSAXTools handler = new XMLSAXTools();

    // Finally, tell the parser to parse the input and notify the handler
    sp.parse(input, handler);

    // Instead of using the SAXParser.parse() method, which is part of the
    // JAXP API, we could also use the SAX1 API directly. Note the
    // difference between the JAXP class javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser and
    // the SAX1 class org.xml.sax.Parser
    //
    // org.xml.sax.Parser parser = sp.getParser(); // Get the SAX parser
    // parser.setDocumentHandler(handler); // Set main handler
    // parser.setErrorHandler(handler); // Set error handler
    // parser.parse(input); // Parse!
}

StringBuffer accumulator = new StringBuffer(); // Accumulate parsed text

String servletName; // The name of the servlet

String servletClass; // The class name of the servlet

String servletId; // Value of id attribute of <servlet> tag

// When the parser encounters plain text (not XML elements), it calls
// this method, which accumulates them in a string buffer
public void characters(char[] buffer, int start, int length) {
    accumulator.append(buffer, start, length);
}

// Every time the parser encounters the beginning of a new element, it
// calls this method, which resets the string buffer
public void startElement(String name, AttributeList attributes) {
    accumulator.setLength(0); // Ready to accumulate new text
    if (name.equals("item")) {
        logger.info("item tag opened");
        counter++;
    }
}

// When the parser encounters the end of an element, it calls this method
public void endElement(String name) {
    if (name.equals("item")) {
        logger.info("item tag closed. Counter: " + counter);
    }
}

/** This method is called when warnings occur */
public void warning(SAXParseException exception) {
    System.err.println("WARNING: line " + exception.getLineNumber() + ": "
            + exception.getMessage());
}

/** This method is called when errors occur */
public void error(SAXParseException exception) {
    System.err.println("ERROR: line " + exception.getLineNumber() + ": "
            + exception.getMessage());
}

/** This method is called when non-recoverable errors occur. */
public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
    System.err.println("FATAL: line " + exception.getLineNumber() + ": "
            + exception.getMessage());
    throw (exception);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    XMLSAXTools t = new XMLSAXTools();

    try {
        t.test();
    } catch (Exception e){
        logger.error("Exception in XMLSAXTools: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You may need to check StAX parsing.                               http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/tutorial/doc/SJSXP2.html

Comment: For a 35GB file I also think StAX. Try this answer has more info:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9382164/458008

Answer (score 8):

You are filling up your `accumulator` without ever emptying it - this is unlikely to be what you want.

Just using SAX is not sufficient to ensure you do not run out of memory - you still need to implement the code that finds, selects and processes what you **do** need from the xml and **discards the rest**.

Here's a fairly simple parser that is designed to be run in a separate thread. It communicates with the calling thread via n `ArrayBlockingQueue<String> queue` which is defined in an enclosing class.

The huge data files I have to deal with are essentially `<Batch> ... a few thousand items ... </Batch>`. This parser pulls each item out and presents them one-at-a-time through the blocking queue. One day I will turn them into `XOM Element`s but atm it uses `String`s.

Notice how it clears down its temporary data fields when `enque` is called to ensure we don't run out of memory:

```
    private class Parser extends DefaultHandler {
      // Track the depth of the xml - whenever we hit level 1 we add the accumulated xml to the queue.
      private int level = 0;
      // The current xml fragment.
      private final StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
      // We've had a start tag but no data yet.
      private boolean tagWithNoData = false;

      /*
       * Called when the starting of the Element is reached. For Example if we have Tag
       * called <Title> ... </Title>, then this method is called when <Title> tag is
       * Encountered while parsing the Current XML File. The AttributeList Parameter has
       * the list of all Attributes declared for the Current Element in the XML File.
       */
      @Override
      public void startElement(final String uri, final String localName, final String name, final Attributes atrbts) throws SAXException {
        checkForAbort();
        // Have we got back to level 1 yet?
        if (level == 1) {

          // Emit any built ones.
          try {
            enqueue();
          } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Throwables.rethrow(ex);
          }
        }

        // Add it on.
        if (level > 0) {
          // The name.
          xml.append("<").append(name);
          // The attributes.
          for (int i = 0; i < atrbts.getLength(); i++) {
            final String att = atrbts.getValue(i);

            xml.append(" ").append(atrbts.getQName(i)).append("=\"").append(XML.to(att)).append("\"");
          }
          // Done.
          xml.append(">");

          // Remember we've not had any data yet.
          tagWithNoData = true;
        }

        // Next element is a sub-element.
        level += 1;
      }

      /*
       * Called when the Ending of the current Element is reached. For example in the
       * above explanation, this method is called when </Title> tag is reached
       */
      @Override
      public void endElement(final String uri, final String localName, final String name) throws SAXException {
        checkForAbort();

        if (level > 1) {
          if (tagWithNoData) {

            // No data. Make the > into a />
            xml.insert(xml.length() - 1, "/");
            // I've closed this one but the enclosing one has data (i.e. this one).
            tagWithNoData = false;
          } else {

            // Had data, finish properly.
            xml.append("</").append(name).append(">");
          }
        }

        // Done with that level.
        level -= 1;

        if (level == 1) {
          // Finished and at level 1.
          try {

            // Enqueue the results.
            enqueue();
          } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Throwables.rethrow(ex);
          }
        }
      }

      /*
       * Called when the data part is encountered.
       */
      @Override
      public void characters(final char buf[], final int offset, final int len) throws SAXException {
        checkForAbort();

        // I want it trimmed.
        final String chs = new String(buf, offset, len).trim();

        if (chs.length() > 0) {
          // Grab that data.
          xml.append(XML.to(chs));
          tagWithNoData = false;
        }
      }

      /*
       * Called when the Parser starts parsing the Current XML File.
       */
      @Override
      public void startDocument() throws SAXException {

        checkForAbort();
        tagWithNoData = false;
      }

      /*
       * Called when the Parser Completes parsing the Current XML File.
       */
      @Override
      public void endDocument() throws SAXException {

        checkForAbort();

        try {

          // Enqueue the results.
          enqueue();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          Throwables.rethrow(ex);
        }
      }

      private void enqueue() throws InterruptedException, SAXException {
        // We may have been closed while blocking on the queue.
        checkForAbort();
        final String x = xml.toString().trim();

        if (x.length() > 0) {
          // Add it to the queue.
          queue.put(x);

          // Clear out.
          xml.setLength(0);
          tagWithNoData = false;

        }
        // We may have been closed while blocking on the queue.
        checkForAbort();
      }

      private void checkForAbort() throws XMLInnerDocumentIteratorAbortedException {
        if (iteratorFinished) {
          LOGGER.debug("Aborting!!!");

          throw new XMLInnerDocumentIterator.XMLInnerDocumentIteratorAbortedException("Aborted!");
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I am trying to run your code, but I think I am missing some libraries. Can you provide me your Maven entries or otherwise a list of libraries you are using. In particular i would like to know what that XML object is...

Comment: @RalfB - The XML class is just a few useful static methods. I would suggest you just remove anything that does not compile. I deliberately chose code that does not fully work so that you would understand a lot more about it before you got it working. Please guess or remove anything that doesnt work. I think I covered your main issue in my first sentence.