# Is it possible to combine XML parsers in JAVA?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, sax

Is it possible to "split" XML tree to more subsets and then use different parsers for parsing?

DOM parser puts whole document to memory and then analyze it, so i guess there is no point to use that for reading subsets.
Could i use Push and pull parsers(SAX and StAX) for parsing subsets?

thanks

Comment: The following may help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169978/split-1gb-xml-file-using-java/5170415#5170415

Comment: I  have 3GB XML file on which i would like to use DOM(on one small part of XML), then SAX and StAX. Best thing for DOM would be to create new XML file with StAX and then read that new XML with DOM. I am not searching for complete code, i am not looking for code what so ever, more like discussion. Thanks

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan: thanks. Actually my question is bad... i am looking for something like: When is it good to combine StAX and SAX for reading XML files

Comment: I have added an answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17296182/383861

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Actually my question is bad... i am looking for something like: When
>   is it good to combine StAX and SAX for reading XML files

Whenever possible I would recommend sticking with the StAX APIs.  They are faster and IMHO are easier to use than SAX.  The exception to this when you are using a `ContentHandler` to process the XML then SAX is easier.  If you hava a StAX `XMLStreamReader` and need to interact with a `ContentHandler` then you could use a `Transformer` for this.

```
StAXSource source = new StAXSource(xmlStreamReader);
SAXResult result = new SAXResult(conentHandler);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```