# Unmarshalling if stream contains collection?

Tags: java, jaxb

I have two classes at the moment. `Customer` and `CustomerItem`, each `Customer` can contain multiple `CustomerItems`:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Customer")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer implements Serializable {

  private final String customerNumber;
  private final String customerName;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "customerItems")
    @XmlElement(name = "CustomerItem")
    private List<CustomerItem> customerItems;
...
```

Via REST we can get a `List<Customer>`, which will result in an XML looking like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
 <collection>
  <Customer>
    // normal values
    <customerItems> 
      <customerItem>
        // normal values
      </customerItem>
    </customerItems>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    ...
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    ...
  </Customer>
</collection>
```

Now if I want to unmarshal the response I get an error:

> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"",
>   local:"collection"). Expected elements are
>   <{}Customer>,<{}CustomerItem>

```
private List<Customer> getCustomersFromResponse(HttpResponse response)
    throws JAXBException, IllegalStateException, IOException {

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(content);

    java.util.List<Customer> unmarshal = (List<Customer>) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
    return unmarshal;

}
```

Now I know why it's not working, obviously Jaxb expects Customer to be the root element, but now find a collection (which seems to be a default value when a List gets returned?).

A workaround would be to create a new Customers class which contains a list of customer and make it the root element, but actually I wouldn't want a new class.

There must be a way to tell jaxb that I have a list of the classes I want to get and that he should look inside the collection tag or something like that?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see here two ways.

1) Create special wrapper class with `@XmlRootElement(name = "collection")` and set it against unmarshaller.

2) Another way - split input `xml` into smaller one using simple `SAX` parser implementation and then parse each fragment separately with `JAXB` (see: [Split 1GB Xml file using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169978/split-1gb-xml-file-using-java)).

I don't think that you can simply tell `JAXB`: parse me this `xml` as set of elements of type `XXX`.

Comment: Thanks, guess we have to go with a wrapper class then.