# Java - Split XML file that contains many loops

Tags: java, xml, split, talend

My question is simple for some and just impossible for others (like me)

I have an XML file and I want to split it into small XML files, of course I've to split it when I reach certain count on `<DOCUMENT>` Element, I've to put 60 `<DOCUMENT>` in each small XML file.

My document is formated like that :

```
<DOCS>
      <PIL>
          <ELEMENT1>
          <ELEMENT2>                   
          <ELEMENT1>
      <PIL>
      <DOCUMENT>
          <ELEMENT1>
          <ELEMENT2>
          <ELEMENT3>
          <ELEMENT4>
                <SUBELEMENT1>
                            <ELEMENT1>
                            <ELEMENT1>
                            <ELEMENT1>
                </SUBELEMENT1>
                <SUBELEMENT2>
                            <ELEMENT1>
                            <ELEMENT1>
                            <ELEMENT1>
                </SUBELEMENT2>
          </ELEMENT4>
          <ELEMENT5>
          <ELEMENT6>
      </DOCUMENT>
</DOCS>
```

So my question is how can I split it having 60 `<DOCUMENT>` in each file ? and do it very quick.

If someone have a solution using Talend that would be great. knowing that using tXMLOutput I can split it but it will only take one element from each loop and all the element of my "document" loop

Comment: 1. get the content
  2. split it
  3. then create files based on the split result

Comment: thanks for asking differently

Answer (score 1):

You can you Stax API for reading the file and then put 60 of this element in a new file. For an example you can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169978/split-1gb-xml-file-using-java/5170415#5170415)

In the example the file is created for each element. In your problem you can create a different file every 60 iterations like this

```
int counter=0;
int fileNumber=1;
File file = new File("out/split1.xml");
StreamResult sr=new StreamResult(file);
while(xsr.nextTag() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
    counter++;
    if (counter>60) {
       counter=0;
       fileNumber++;
       file = new File("out/split"+fileNumber+".xml");
       sr=new StreamResult(file);
    }
    t.transform(new StAXSource(xsr), sr);
}
```

Comment: I tried the option below but I can get it to put every 60 element in a new file

Comment: I tried this method but it creates a file every 60 element containing only one `<DOCUMENT>` element (it doesen't append the all of the 60 elements)

Comment: Also with this method I loose the `<PIL>` Element and everything inside it.