# Split the xml into smaller one based on change in tag values

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0, stax

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<ABC>
    <END />
    <Tables>
        <START>
            <row>
                <id>111</id>
                <name>abc</name>
                <deptId>1</deptId>
            </row>
            <row>
                <id>112</id>
                <name>abc1</name>
                <deptId>1</deptId>
            </row>
            <row>
                <id>113</id>
                <name>abc3</name>
                <deptId>1</deptId>
            </row>
            <row>
                <id>222</id>
                <name>def</name>
                <deptId>2</deptId>
            </row>
            <row>
                <id>333</id>
                <name>pqr</name>
                <deptId>2</deptId>
            </row>
            <row>
                <id>444</id>
                <name>xyz</name>
                <deptId>2</deptId>
            </row>
            <row>
                <id>555</id>
                <name>lmn</name>
                <deptId>3</deptId>
            </row>
            <row>
                <id>555</id>
                <name>lmn</name>
                <deptId>3</deptId>
            </row>
        </START>
    </Tables>
</ABC>
```

I have a xml with the above structure. I have to spilt the xml into 3 xmls based on the different `deptId`.
I have to Split the xml into smaller one based on change in tag values. My elemement is `deptId` whose values is been changes after some rows.
The all elements with same `deptId` are in a sequence.

The required output is : 
Its good to have the xml name as the department id.

The first xml be with name `1.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<ABC>
    <END />
    <Tables>
        <START>
            <row>
                <id>111</id>
                <name>abc</name>
                <deptId>1</deptId>
            </row>
            <row>
                <id>112</id>
                <name>abc1</name>
                <deptId>1</deptId>
            </row>
            <row>
                <id>113</id>
                <name>abc3</name>
                <deptId>1</deptId>
            </row>
        </START>
    </Tables>
</ABC>
```

The second xml with name 2.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<ABC>
    <END />
    <Tables>
        <START>
            <row>
                <id>222</id>
                <name>def</name>
                <deptId>2</deptId>
            </row>
            <row>
                <id>333</id>
                <name>pqr</name>
                <deptId>2</deptId>
            </row>
            <row>
                <id>444</id>
                <name>xyz</name>
                <deptId>2</deptId>
            </row>
        </START>
    </Tables>
</ABC>
```

The third xml with name 3.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<ABC>
    <END />
    <Tables>
        <START>
            <row>
                <id>113</id>
                <name>abc3</name>
                <deptId>1</deptId>
            </row>
        </START>
    </Tables>
</ABC>
```

I had tried with the `StAXSource` option by referring couple of option
The option I have tried are by referring below links

[Split xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169978/split-1gb-xml-file-using-java?noredirect=1&lq=1)
[Split large xml](https://dzone.com/articles/splitting-large-xml-files-java)

Here is the sample piece of code that have been tried.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

public class Demo2 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLStreamReader streamReader = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("D://SmallXmltoSplit.xml"));

    streamReader.nextTag(); // Advance to next element
    streamReader.nextTag();
    streamReader.nextTag();
    streamReader.nextTag();
    streamReader.nextTag();
    streamReader.nextTag();

    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
    String deptId = null;
    File file = new File("D://test" + ".xml");
    while (streamReader.hasNext()) {
        if (streamReader.isStartElement()) {
            if (streamReader.getLocalName().equals("deptId")) {
                if (deptId == null) {
                    deptId = streamReader.getElementText();
                    file = new File("D://" + deptId + ".xml");
                    t.transform(new StAXSource(streamReader), new StreamResult(file));
                } else if (deptId != streamReader.getElementText()) {
                    file = new File("D://" + deptId + ".xml");
                    t.transform(new StAXSource(streamReader), new StreamResult(file));
                } 
            }
            t.transform(new StAXSource(streamReader), new StreamResult(file));
        }
        streamReader.next();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier to do this with XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform version="2.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="//row" group-adjacent="deptId">
      <xsl:result-document href="{current-grouping-key()}.xml">
        <ABC>
         <END />
          <Tables>
           <START>
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
           </START>
          </Tables>
        </ABC>
      </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

To run this from a Java application, you will want to download Saxon, and then invoke it for example with this logic:

```
    Processor proc = new Processor(false);
    XsltCompiler comp = proc.newXsltCompiler();
    XsltExecutable exp = comp.compile(new StreamSource(new File("my-stylesheet.xsl")));
    Serializer out = proc.newSerializer(new File("output.xml"));
    Xslt30Transformer trans = exp.load30();
    trans.applyTemplates(new StreamSource(new File("input.xml"), out);
```

More details here: http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!using-xsl/embedding/s9api-transformation

Comment: Could you guide me how do I execute the same?

Comment: I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The XML reading should go by `<row>`, more or less as follows:

```
    XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    // Do not use a Reader, especially not a FileReader. An InputStream leaves the
    // encoding of the XML to the XMLStreamReader.
    InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("D:/SmallXmltoSplit.xml"));
    XMLStreamReader streamReader = xif.createXMLStreamReader(in);
    streamReader.nextTag();

    String id = "";
    String name = "";
    String deptId = "";

    String oldDeptId = null;
```

//      File file = new File("D:/test" + ".xml");

```
    while (streamReader.hasNext()) {
        if (streamReader.isStartElement()) {
            switch (streamReader.getLocalName()) {
            case "row":
                id = "";
                name = "";
                deptId = "";
                break;
            case "id":
                id = streamReader.getElementText();
                break;
            case "name":
                name = streamReader.getElementText();
                break;
            case "deptId":
                deptId = streamReader.getElementText();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (streamReader.isEndElement()) {
            switch (streamReader.getLocalName()) {
            case "START":
                if (oldDeptId != null) {
                    saveDept();
                    //oldDeptId = deptId;
                }
                break;
            case "row":
                if (!deptId.equals(oldDeptId)) {
                    if (oldDeptId != null) {
                        saveDept();
                        oldDeptId = deptId;
                    }
                    startDept(deptId);
                }
                appendDeptRow(id, name, deptId);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The writing can be done without transformation; in fact it could be done as text.

I leave that as an excercise.

FileReader and FileWriter should not be used, as they encode the bytes using the default platform encoding. The class `Files` has many nice file functions.

Another specialty here is the UTF-16 encoding which doubles the size of an almost ASCII file. As you mention having a large file, it would be best to keep that file in UTF-8, probably even if the names are in Farsi, Greek, Japanese or Bulgarian.